# Physical intuition behind the fact that current in an inductor lags behind the emf/voltage by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in an AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, inductance

What exactly is the reason that current through an inductor in an AC circuit acquires maximum value after quarter a time period ($\frac{T}{4}$) of the emf getting the max value?

Comment: Well, I suppose one could argue that the phase of the AC current through an inductor has to be either +90 or -90 degrees out of phase with that of the AC voltage across an inductor because otherwise there would be a net, time-averaged power loss to the inductor and that's not possible with an ideal inductor which doesn't dissipate energy but only reversibly stores and releases energy.

Comment: I understand the mathematical reasons for this,i just wanted to know the physical intuition behind the idea of current reaching its max value with a phase difference of 90 degrees after the voltage.Like when the voltage is applied,does the current wait till voltage has completed 1/4th of its cycle to start?

Comment: No, obviously the current doesn't know anything about the past history or future behavior of the voltage. The current has no 'memory' about events like that. At each instant in time it simply reacts to the instantaneous voltage according to the equation dI/dt=V(t)/L, where L is the inductance. For a voltage sine wave it turns out that the current is the exact same shape and delayed by exactly 1/4 cycle but I think that that's specific to sine waves and cannot be generalized. You might try calculating the current response to, for example, an AC voltage square wave to see what happens.